# Is this a noun constructed from a verb?

Tags: verb, sentence-structure, noun

Can someone kindly explain the structure of this sentence to me (in general terms)?

I am most confused about the following:

- The verb looks like it is in position 3
- What is 'Trainierte' in this case? It seems to refer to a 'trained' person, 
  but I thought this would have to be used as an adjective in conjunction with 
  a noun (i.e trained man/woman/person).

> Vor allem **Trainierte** können sich eher am unteren Bereich der Empfehlung orientieren

Many thanks,

Comment: It is a verb transformed to a pronoun and then transformed to a noun. :-) "Particularly trained (persons) are more likely...".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and format feedback!

Answer (score 4):

*The verb looks like it is in position 3.*

This is not how the V2 rule works. V2 is the last resort. The finite verb is neither at the beginning nor the end so it **must** be in second position (though there is, of course, an exception even to this rule). This means

> Vor allem Trainierte

is **one item**. Because V2 says, all the stuff in front of the finite verb in second position is one item. (Apart from particles. Particles break any rule.)

In this case, it's the subject: *trained persons in particular*.

---

*What is 'Trainierte' in this case?*

It's a noun made from the *Partizip II* of the verb *trainieren*: *trainiert*. You can make different nouns from a verb

> das Trainieren — practising (from *Infinitiv*)
>
> der Trainierende — the practising one (from *Partizip I*)
>
> der Trainierte — the one who has practiced (from *Partizip II*, perfect interpretation)
>
> der Trainierte — the one who is coached (from *Partizip II*, passive interpretation)

This systematic is applicable to **all** German verbs and German speakers use it all the time. Some verbs allow one more form

> die Platzierung — the result of platzieren *("-ung-Form")*

This doesn't apply to *trainieren* though, for unknown reasons. Maybe because people differ what the result of *trainieren* is.

Comment: Perfect. Was unaware of Partizip II verb transformations given the level I am currently studying at - great explanation, thanks.

Comment: *Vor allem Trainierte* is one item because *Vor allem* is an attributive of *Trainierte*. If it weren't, the word order would in fact violate V2.